# MDX Query Wild Card Search

Tags: mdx, ssrs-2012

Can any one help me on how to perform a wild card search in `MDX` queries?

For example I have a parameter called TestName in my `SSRS` report.Default value of the parameter is `[Dim Test Master].[Test Name].[ALL]`. So when a test name is searched as say for example `quli%` it should return qualitative test in the result.
I have tried using `INSTR` but it asks for some default value. In my case I cannot predict what my test name can be ,so if i give a false default value i will not get expected out put. This was my insert query

```
 SELECT 
 Filter( 
    [Dim Test Master].[Test Name].[Test Name].ALLMEMBERS
   ,Instr([Dim Test Master].[Test Name].currentmember.Properties( 'Member_Caption' ), @TName )  > 0
```

when the report opens all test names should be displayed by default and when i search for one that particular searched test must be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SSAS Multidimensional I would recommend deploying ASSP and using one of these string searching wildcard functions. I think that will be much more straightforward than attempting to use InStr:
http://asstoredprocedures.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StringFilters&referringTitle=Home